# about receiving float on matlab from ATmega32 Avr

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, avr, matlab

****i am using ATmega32 to send float and want to receive it on matlab,i send 4.85 from ATmega32 but on matlab i receive 4.260233679216239e-31...can any one help me..thanks in advance**
**

```
    //Atmel studio code++++code for sending float from Atmega32
    union abc{ float fo; unsigned long lo; };
 union abc data; 
int main(void)
 { usart_init();
 data.fo=4.85;
 while(1) {
for(int i=0; i<=24; i+=8) 
{
    uart_send(data.lo>>i); }}}

 //Matlab code for receiving float 
s=serial('COM1','BaudRate',9600); 
fopen(s); 
out=fread(s,1,'single'); 
 fclose(s);
```

Answer (score 2):

i found the solution for this problem, i set a header before sending the data from ATmega32,and on Matlab i check the frame ,if it received correctly,i receive the data

```
//ATmega32 code
    float x =215.5;
    unsigned char *ptrx;
    int main(void)
    {   usart_init();
        //data.fo=12.85;


        ptrx=( unsigned char *) &x;
          while(1)
       {
        uart_send(0xAA);//equals to 170 
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        uart_send(*(ptrx+i));}

        x++;}}
    //on Matlab
    s=serial('COM1','BaudRate',9600);
    fopen(s);
     i=1;
    while i<1000
        header =fread(s,1,'uint8');

        if header==170//equal to 0xAA

     out=fread(s,1,'float');
    data(i)=out;

     i=i+1;
        end
     end
    fclose(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

The binary representation of 4.260233679216239e-31 is `0x0d0a40a3`. The
first two bytes (in big endian format) are `0x0d` and `0x0a`, which
happen to be the ASCII characters CR and LF. These characters, in
tandem, are often used as line terminators. My guess is that
`uart_send()` is not doing what you think...

I suggest using `Serial.write()` instead. This way you won't have
unwanted line terminators. And it will also make your problem on-topic
with respect to this site.

Also, do not send the bytes repeatedly, send them only once, on demand.
If you send them continuously, Matlab may catch the serial stream in the
middle of a number, and assemble the bytes in the wrong order.